# How to convert text to Float and print in a new div the result of account

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, price

I'm trying get a string in a div, remove the content of this one, and after this get the real price in ".skuBestPrice" remove special chars and do an account to convert in a float number and finish printing this number in the div ".totalPrice", but is not working correctly, what's the issue? Thanks!!!

```js
 /* Transform String in Number */
        $(document).ready(function() {
          function formatPrice() {
         //$('.totalPrice').empty();
         var price = parseFloat($.trim($('.skuBestPrice').html()).replace(",", "").replace("$", "").val());
         var total = (parseFloat(price)/100).toFixed(2);
         //$(".totalPrice").val(total);
           document..getElementsByClassName(".totalPrice").innerHTML = total;
          }
         //$(document).on("load", "strong", formatPrice);
        });
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: you have to use document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Should `25,11` converts to `2511` or `25.11` ?

Comment: Should converts to 25,11

Comment: `25,11` <-- comma or dot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of little errors. Chaining functions off wrong items, wrong inputs.... Here is the reduced fixed version.

```js
 var price = parseFloat($.trim($('.skuBestPrice').html().replace(",", "").replace("$", "")));
 var total = (parseFloat(price)/100).toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = '$'+total;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<!-- * Here are the correct value converted -->
<div id="totalPrice">$ <span class="total">the final price should print here.</span></div>

<div class="price-best-price" style="display: block;">Por: 
 <strong class="skuBestPrice">$ 25,11</strong>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your markup to

```
<div id="totalPrice">$ <span class="total">the final price should print here.</span></div>

<div class="price-best-price" style="display: block;">Por: 
    <strong class="skuBestPrice">$ 25,11</strong>
</div>
```

reason is you are using getElementById on a class name, you have to specify id. If you can't change the markup then use document.getElementsByClassName('totalPrice')[0]

```
document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = total;
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('totalPrice')[0].innerHtml = total;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to extract numbers from your string as shown below and then parse it to float. Also if you want to extract value between tags then use **text()** instead of **val()**

```js
/* Transform String in Number */
$(document).ready(function() {
  function formatPrice() {
 //$('.totalPrice').empty();
     var p= $(".skuBestPrice").text().replace(/[^0-9\+]/g, '');    
     var price = parseFloat(p);
     var total = (parseFloat(price)/100).toFixed(2);
     //$(".totalPrice").val(total);
      $(".total").text(total);
  }
 //$(document).on("load", "strong", formatPrice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<!-- * Here are the correct value converted -->
<div class="totalPrice">$ <span class="total">the final price should print here.</span></div>

<div class="price-best-price" style="display: block;">Por: 
 <strong class="skuBestPrice">$ 25,11</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: `$ the final price should print here`!

Answer (score 1):

It should work. make some changes in html and javascript

```js
/* Transform String in Number */
$(function() {
  //function formatPrice() {
 //$('.totalPrice').empty();
  var val = $('.skuBestPrice').html();
 var price = val.replace("$", "").replace(",", "")
    //console.log(price);
    //parseFloat("554,20".replace(",", "."));
 var total = (parseFloat(price)/100).toFixed(2);
   document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = total;
  
});
```

```html
  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br /><br />
<!-- * Here are the correct value converted -->
<span id="totalPrice">$</span> <span class="total">the final price should print here.</span>

<div class="price-best-price" style="display: block;">Por: 
 <strong class="skuBestPrice">$ 25,11</strong>
</div>
```